# Read in Bash script not splitting after IFS on Xubuntu 14.10

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting

I wrote a script to parse a log file for a university project which is required to run on xubuntu 14.10. The script works fine on Ubuntu and Windows Subsystem for Linux but not on Xubuntu. After some debugging, i found that the line failing is the read:

```
IFS=${tab}

case ${line:0:2} in
    "C${tab}")
        read -r code customer_id time_supermarket time_queue\
                changed_queues products_count <<< ${line}
     ...
```

The read seems to ignore the IFS and use the newline as separator, because it copies the line inside the variable code, and no splitting is performed.
I'm assuming it recognizes the tab inside the line variable beacuse it matches the `"C${tab}"` in the case statement correctly.
Moreover, if I print `"a${IFS}b` before the read, I get `"a    b"`.

Below is the full script and a small sample of testing cases (note that stackoverflow replaces tabs with spaces, on my system there are tabs between each value, and unix line endings).

Thanks to anyone reading.

```
#!/bin/bash

file=./logs/supermarket.log

#use . (dot) in printf float even in systems
#   that use , (comma) by default
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"

tab=$(printf '\t')

declare -a cashier_total_time_to_serve
declare -a cashier_total_time_open
declare -a cashier_elaborated_prodcuts
declare -a cashier_served_customers
declare -a cashier_closures_count

printf "Customers:\n"
printf "┌────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┐\n"
printf "│   ID   │ #PRODS │SPRMTIME│SRVSTIME│ #QUEUE │\n"
printf "├────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┤\n"
while IFS=$'\n' read -r line; do

    IFS=${tab}

    case ${line:0:2} in
        "C${tab}")
            read -r code customer_id time_supermarket time_queue\
                    changed_queues products_count <<< ${line}
            printf "│ %6d │ %6d │ %6.3f │ %6.3f │ %6d │\n" \
                ${customer_id} ${products_count} ${time_supermarket} \
                ${time_queue} ${changed_queues}
            ;;

        "K${tab}")
            read -r code cashier_id served_customers\
                    elaborated_products closures_count <<< ${line}
            cashier_elaborated_prodcuts[${cashier_id}]=${elaborated_products}
            cashier_served_customers[${cashier_id}]=${served_customers}
            cashier_closures_count[${cashier_id}]=${closures_count}
            ;;

        "KC")
            read -r code cashier_id customer_id \
                    time_to_serve <<< ${line}

            if [ -z "${cashier_total_time_to_serve[${cashier_id}]}" ]
            then
                cashier_total_time_to_serve[${cashier_id}]=0
            fi

            temp=$(echo ${cashier_total_time_to_serve[${cashier_id}]} + ${time_to_serve} | bc -l)
            cashier_total_time_to_serve[${cashier_id}]=${temp}
            ;;

        "KS")
            read -r code cashier_id time_workshift <<< ${line}

            if [ -z "${cashier_total_time_open[${cashier_id}]}" ]
            then
                cashier_total_time_open[${cashier_id}]=0
            fi

            temp=$(echo ${cashier_total_time_open[${cashier_id}]} + ${time_workshift} | bc -l)
            cashier_total_time_open[${cashier_id}]=${temp}
            ;;
        *)
            ;;
    esac

done < $file
printf "└────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┘\n"


printf "\n"
printf "Cashiers: \n"

printf "┌────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┐\n"
printf "│   ID   │ #PRODS │#CUSTMRS│OPENTIME│AVGSERVC│ #CLOSE │\n"
printf "├────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┤\n"

cashiers_count=${#cashier_closures_count[@]}

for (( i=0; i<$cashiers_count; i++ ))
do
    cashier_avg_time_to_serve=$(echo ${cashier_total_time_to_serve[$i]} / ${cashier_served_customers[$i]} | bc -l)

    printf "│ %6d │ %6d │ %6d │ %6.3f │ %6.3f │ %6d │\n" \
        $i ${cashier_elaborated_prodcuts[$i]} \
        ${cashier_served_customers[$i]} ${cashier_total_time_open[$i]} \
        $cashier_avg_time_to_serve ${cashier_closures_count[$i]}
done
printf "└────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┘\n"
```

```
KC  0   40  0.046
C   40  0.075   0.046   0   1
KC  0   12  0.082
C   12  0.157   0.127   0   19
KS  0   1.075
KS  3   1.107
K   1   102 5303    5
K   4   111 5662    5
```

Comment: Please paste your script there first: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know this tool. I figured the problem out, I'll write the solution in the answer!

Answer (score 1):

As Cyrus commented on the question, I used shellcheck.net which told me to "Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting." on `${line}`.

This is the corrected snippet:

```
IFS=${tab}

case ${line:0:2} in
    "C${tab}")
        read -r code customer_id time_supermarket time_queue\
                changed_queues products_count <<< "${line}"
     ...
```